# Is there a way to concatenate Java strings in less than O(n) time?

Tags: java, string-concatenation

My homework question involves joining strings in a particular sequence. We are first given the strings, followed by a set of instructions that tell us how to concatenate them; finally we print the output string.

I have used the Kattis FastIO class to handle buffered input and output. Below is my algorithm, which iterates through the instructions to concatenate the strings. I have tried making the array of normal strings, StringBuffers and StringBuilders.

The program seems to work as intended, but it gives a time limit error on my submission platform due to inefficiency. It seems like appending the way I did is O(n); is there any faster way?

```
public class JoinStrings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Kattio io = new Kattio(System.in, System.out);
        ArrayList<StringBuilder> stringList = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
        int numStrings = io.getInt();
        StringBuilder[] stringArray = new StringBuilder[numStrings];

        for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++) {
            String str = io.getWord();
            stringArray[i] = new StringBuilder(str);
        }

        StringBuilder toPrint = stringArray[0]; 

        while (io.hasMoreTokens()) {
            int a = io.getInt();
            int b = io.getInt();
            stringArray[a-1].append(stringArray[b-1]); // this is the line that is done N times

            toPrint = stringArray[a-1];
        }

        io.println(toPrint.toString());
        io.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: `stringArray[a-1].append(stringArray[b-1]);` itself is `O(n)`. The loop makes your program run in `O(n^2)` time. This is because `append(...)` makes use of `System.arraycopy` which is a native method with a complexity of `O(n)`.

Comment: We need more information about the problem. The result can be exponential in size (e.g. if you append string to itself). If you have to output this result, there is nothing you can do (and `StringBuilder` is one of the most efficient solutions). So there are some assumptions which you didn't tell us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `StringBuilder.append()` copy char from new string to existing string. It's fast but not free.

Instead of keeping appending the String to the StringBuilder array, keep track of the String indexes need to appended. Then finally append the Strings stored in the print out indexes list.

Comment: Yes I believe that last point about keeping track of the final concat operation is the key to solving this fast, because no matter what, string concatenation in Java is `O(N)` where `N` is the size of both strings

Comment: @smac89 yeah. So instead of appending Strings, we keep a list of indexes in appending order only. The longer the Strings, the more efficient we can get :D

Comment: Hmm, okay. Is it actually faster to concat all N strings at the end though? I feel like if I'm iterating over the collection of strings just to concatenate them, it'll be the same complexity as before?

Comment: @RyanChng, don't do separate concats. In fact don't do concats because you may run out of memory. If this was C, I'd suggest using `putc` to print each char immediately. In Java, try doing it with a `BufferedOutputStream`. My recommendation though is to just avoid actually concating all the strings in memory before printing because that's just doing double the work which your IO system should handle via a buffer

Comment: @smac89 thanks, I developed a solution that involved determining the sequence of the indices (as per Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn's suggestion), and then used a print function to simply print them in one line. It's buggy and fails private test cases, but does a good job of not concatenating.

Comment: @RyanChng The idea is instead of appending the String, you append/prepend the indexes to form a list of indexes that represents the computed String. Append the String at index `j` to String at index `i` will become list of [i, j] Then finally print/concat the output String. This is far more better than concat Strings because your String length with typically far greater than 1 anyway

Comment: Yep @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn that is what I have! Thanks!